# Rundeck node configuration failed

Tags: rundeck, winrm

Rundeck is returning an error when I try to execute a script on a new remote node.

```
[overthere-winrm:172.16.58.78] failed: WinRM Error:
Unexpected HTTP response on http://172.16.58.78:5985/wsman: (401)
Failed: WinRMProtocolError:WinRM Error: 
Unexpected HTTP response on http://172.16.58.78:5985/wsman: (401)
```

This is the new node config in `rundeck` config file.

```
_myNewNode:
  description: "_myNewNode"
  tags: "windows"
  hostname: "_myIp"
  osArch: "amd64"
  osFamily: "windows"
  node-executor: "overthere-winrm"
  winrm-auth-type: "basic"
  winrm-cmd: "CMD"
  winrm-protocol: "http"
  username: "_myUsername"
  winrm-password-storage-path: "keys/_myPassword"
```

This is the WinRM config for my new node.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = false
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts = *
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = true
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
        MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647
```

I've tried multiple solutions given on the internet but still couldn't solve it.
Telnetting from my rundeck server to the new node, there don't seem to be a problem. Port `5985` is up and listening.

```
Poroto Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:5985           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: Could you try with the PyWinRM plugin? Overthere WinRM plugin is an unmaintained plugin right now. PyWinRM is included out of the box with Rundeck; take a look at this: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin#rundeck-python-winrm-plugin

Answer (score 0):

The WinRM plugin is out of support right now, try with the [PyWinRM](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin), is out of the box with Rundeck and is active supported, also avoids some [bugs](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/8148) related to the latest Rundeck version. [Here](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin#rundeck-python-winrm-plugin) how to config the plugin.